# Juniper MX/SRX series interface monitoring command

Tags: routing, juniper, juniper-srx, juniper-mx

Good morning all,

I was curious due to an issue were currently troubleshooting in our environment if there is a command in Juniper that will allow us to determine the utilization percentage of an interface on the MX480 along with the SRX550 platforms. 
I know "monitor interface ge-2/3/8" for example would give me live rates for the interface referenced in the command however I am looking for interface utilization percentages versus bits/sec or packets/sec.

I recall when I worked in predominantly Cisco environments You could obtain this data rather easily. I am just wondering if there is an equivalent in the Juniper world.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you mention what do you mean by 'something more?

Comment: I have edited my above question to reflect what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`monitor interface` and `show interface <...> detail` are the commands most often used. However, I don't think many people use a CLI nowadays to get this information. There are many tools which use either SNMP or (even better) streaming telemetry to retrieve this information from a network device and display it in any way you like.